# Async script downloading with Ember

Tags: ember.js

I know ember is not a fan of AMD. Does ember provide an alternative Asynchronous script download mechanism ? I have a script that does this already. But, how do I configure Ember to hold off on execution till all the files have downloaded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am creating this here just for archiving purposes. Here is a link to the original post on Ember forums and pwagenet's response.

> You can call `MyApp.deferReadiness()` then, when everything is loaded, call
>   `MyApp.advanceReadiness()`. In the future, questions like this are ideal for StackOverflow.

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/async-script-downloading/542/4